# Play YouTube video using webbrowser in python3

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, youtube, web-inspector, python-webbrowser

I want to play YouTube video using Python3. I can open the YouTube video using webbrowser.open(), but then i need to either press space or mouse click the play button to actually play the video. How to automate this, **without using seleinum if possible.**

```
        try:
        client = webbrowser.get("firefox")
        client.open("https://" + open_url)
    except webbrowser.Error as e:
        print(e)
```

In browser's console (inspect element), if I enter

```
document.querySelector('.ytp-play-button').click();
```

the video gets played, is there a way to simply pass this script (anyother alternative will also do the trick).

I am a student, and already know how to use selenium, and was just wondering if there is a simple was to do this one exact thing without selenium.

Oh yeah, when I simply copy past the url into chrome, or firefox tab than video gets played automatically without requiring me to press space or click the play button, if you know the answer to why this than please share it.

Thank you for your feedbacks.

Comment: Apperantly, I have to give firefox permission for autoplay on  YouTube. But I am still not sure why opening YouTube video from python requires permission but directly entering url will autoplay the video. If you know the answer to this please share.

Comment: Because scripting isn't considered "interacted with the document first" since it can be automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play youtube videos using [mpv](https://mpv.io/). In the cmd you can play video [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba7iX.jpg). Now using subprocess or os module you can run that command and play

```
import os
os.system(f"mpv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNeLUngb-Xg")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to press space

```
import time
import webbrowser
import pyautogui

try:
    client = webbrowser.get("firefox")
    client.open("https://" + open_url)
    time.sleep(30)       #give it a couple seconds to load
    pyautogui.press('space')
except webbrowser.Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? It might be accurate, but it isn't a very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(url)
webbrowser.get(browser).open(url)
```

plus there are some other ways too.